# How do I mask for 2-D MultiHeadAttention in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, time-series, masking, attention-model

Can anyone help me understand masking a 3D input (technically 4D) in MultiHeadAttention?

My original dataset consists of timeseries in the form of:

Inputs: `(samples, horizon, features)` ~> `(8, 4, 2)` ~> `K, V, Q during inference`
Targets: `(samples, horizon, features)` ~> `(8, 4, 2)` ~> `Q during training`
Labels: `(sample, horizon, features)` ~> `(1, 4, 2)`

Essentially I'm taking 8 samples of timeseries data and ultimately outputting 1 sample in the same format. Targets are horizon-shifted values of Inputs and fed into an encoder-only Transformer model (`Q, K, V` as shown above).

In order to best approximate the single output sample (which is identical to the last sample in Targets), I need to run full attention on the horizons of each sample and causal attention between samples. Once the data has been run through the encoder, it is sent to an EinsumDense layer which reduces the `(8, 4, 2)` encoder output into `(1, 4, 2)`.  In order for all this to work, I need to inject a 4th dimension on my data, so Inputs and Targets are formatted as `(1, 8, 4, 2)`.

So getting to my actual question, how do I generate the masking for the encoder? After some digging around through errors I noticed that the shape of the tensor that MHA uses for masking the softmax is formatted `(1, 1, 8, 4, 8, 4)` which makes me believe it's `(B, H, TS, TH, SS, SH)` where:

`B`=batch
`H`=heads
`TS`=target samples
`TH`=target horizon
`SS`=source samples
`SH`=source horizon

I gather this notion from [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/MultiHeadAttention) only because of the `attention_output` description:

> ...where T is for target sequence shapes

Assuming this to be the case, is the following a reasonable mask, or is there a more appropriate method:

```
sample_mask = tf.linalg.band_part(tf.ones((samples, samples)), -1, 0)
horizon_mask = tf.ones((horizon, horizon))

encoder_mask = (
    sample_mask[:, tf.newaxis, :, tf.newaxis]
    * horizon_mask[tf.newaxis, :, tf.newaxis, :]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

it is masking you can fancy it since data are contained in many fashions nothing wrong with it but I am trying to use the Tensorflow methods please see the result they are on the same dimensions. [Tensorflow Masking layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Masking)

Sample: Simply identical masking values with target shapes you become observers for the solutions, proved with eyes fashions improved governance.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

start = 3
limit = 25
delta = 3
sample = tf.range(start, limit, delta)
sample = tf.cast( sample, dtype=tf.int64 )
sample = tf.constant( sample, shape=( 8, 1 ) )

horizon = tf.random.uniform(shape=[1, 4], minval=5, maxval=10, dtype=tf.int64)
features = tf.random.uniform(shape=[1, 1, 2], minval=-5, maxval=+5, dtype=tf.int64)

temp = tf.math.multiply(sample, horizon)
temp = tf.expand_dims(temp, axis=2)
input = tf.math.multiply( temp, features )

print( "input: " )
print( input )

n_samples = 8
n_horizon = 4
n_features = 2
sample_mask = tf.linalg.band_part(tf.ones((n_samples, n_samples)), -1, 0)
horizon_mask = tf.ones((n_horizon, n_horizon))

encoder_mask = (
    sample_mask[:, tf.newaxis, :, tf.newaxis]
    * horizon_mask[tf.newaxis, :, tf.newaxis, :]
)

print( encoder_mask )

masking_layer = tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=50, input_shape=(n_horizon, n_features))
print( masking_layer(input) )

img_1 = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(
        tf.constant( tf.constant( input[:,:,1], shape=(8, 4, 1) ), shape=(8, 4, 1) ),
        data_format=None,
        scale=True
    )
    

img_2 = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(
        tf.constant( masking_layer(input)[:,:,0], shape=(8, 4, 1) ),
        data_format=None,
        scale=True
    )

plt.figure(figsize=(1, 2))
plt.title("")
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.grid(False)
plt.imshow(img_1)
plt.xlabel("Input (8, 4, 2), left")

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.grid(False)
plt.imshow(img_2)
plt.xlabel("Masks (8, 4, 2), left")

plt.show()
```

Output: Input tensor we created from table matched features.

```
 [[ -960     0]
  [-1080     0]
  [ -960     0]
  [ -960     0]]], shape=(8, 4, 2), dtype=int64)
```

Output: The question - masking methods.

```
  [[1. 1. 1. 1.]
   [1. 1. 1. 1.]
   [1. 1. 1. 1.]
   ...
   [1. 1. 1. 1.]
   [1. 1. 1. 1.]
   [1. 1. 1. 1.]]]], shape=(8, 4, 8, 4), dtype=float32)
```

Output: The masking_layer = tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=50, input_shape=(n_horizon, n_features))

```
[[ -840     0]
  [ -945     0]
  [ -840     0]
  [ -840     0]]

 [[ -960     0]
  [-1080     0]
  [ -960     0]
  [ -960     0]]], shape=(8, 4, 2), dtype=int64)
```

- [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UySM.png)
- [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sR92.png)

Comment: I see you've essentially recreated a basic working example of my script, but I don't see any changes to the core concept. Are you saying everything looks good as-is? I don't understand what you mean when you wrote: Sample: Simply identical masking values with target shapes you become observers for the solutions, proved with eyes fashions improved governance.

I was hoping for confirmation of my assumption on the meaning and shape of the masking layer with regards to the MultiHeadAttention module in the context of time series batch data.

Comment: I did not say that your method is wrong but you asking anyway todo it then I use the simple Tensorflow masking layer.